# Xamarin.Forms Button Padding Cuts Off FontIcon

Tags: c#, xaml, button, xamarin.forms, padding

I've got a button using a font icon from [Material Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/). (Displaying this icon as well as several others is working fine so converter omitted for brevity). Here is the XAML for the button:

```
<Button Margin="10"
        Padding="0"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Background}"
        CornerRadius="25"
        FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}"
        FontSize="36"
        HeightRequest="50"
        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
        Text="{Binding PlusIcon, Converter={StaticResource NameToIcon}}"
        WidthRequest="50" />
```

As you can see I've got the padding set to 0, but it still displays like this:

[image]

Just to test I have done this with regular text too:

[image]

Looks fine if I set the font size smaller, but this is not what I want:

[image]

How do I force removal of the padding? And why is the text not centered when I change the font size? Issue happens on IOS and Android.

Comment: I am not much aware of how these material icons work but if they work like `FontAwesome` have you tried using a Label here instead?

Comment: This issue seems caused by the custom font (maybe the custom icon has pading in default). Because it works fine on my side (I used the default font).

Comment: @FreakyAli yes exactly the same as FontAwesome. I haven't tried a label, I'll give that a go.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT the image in my question displaying the symptom with regular text (no custom font) demonstrates that this is not correct.

Comment: Did using a label worked out for you?

Comment: @Matt G You could share your sample so that I can test it on my side (as your code works fine on my side ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `ImageButton` with a `FontImageSource`

First you declare you FontImageSource in your styles:

```
<FontImageSource x:Key="IconBikeSmall"
                 FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}"
                 Glyph="{x:Static styles:IconFont.Biking}"
                 Size="{StaticResource SizeSmallIcon}"
                 Color="{StaticResource SecondaryColor}" />
```

Then you simply use it as value for the `Source` property of your button:

```
   <ImageButton Source="{StaticResource IconBikeSmall}"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

Or even use it directly like this:

```
  <ImageButton HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
      <ImageButton.Source> 
          <FontImageSource
                 FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}"
                 Glyph="{x:Static styles:IconFont.Biking}"
                 Size="{StaticResource SizeSmallIcon}"
                 Color="{StaticResource SecondaryColor}" />
      </ImageButton.Source> 
  </ImageButton>
```

Comment: I would actually prefer to use this so I can use the pressed state etc. - I will test and mark as answer if it works.

Comment: Sorry this took so long to get back to you on - this solved my problem and works beautifully! Thank you